# AWS Api Gateway - get spaces in the JSON\ body

Tags: json, aws-api-gateway

I sent with postman some JSON body to AWS API Gateway.
for EX: {"test":"test"}

I'm hashing this body (hmac-sha1).

my problem is when I'm hashing the JSON, i don't use spaces between the ":" in the JSON.
when API gateway get the body JSON is adding spaces in the JSON between the ":".

to avoid future problems  i want to handle the body as is, without manipulate it.

i try use with and without template integration at the API gateway,
with $input.json('$') & $input.body.
empty integration & etc..

the question, how i get the body as is he sent from the client?

thanks.

Comment: what is the reason you are manuputlating the body in integration request? usually, we don't have to do anything, api gateway simply passes it along. whether it is xml or json, or just a string. doesn't really matter.

Comment: the reason is, the client hashing the JSON without a spaces. and when i'm auth the hasing it came with spaces from API gateway and the HMAC-SHA1 not equal.

Comment: it is not problem for me to handle spaces, but it is open a future problems.